# Determinant of non-symmetric sum of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinants

Given three real, symmetric matrices $A\succ0$ and $B$, $C⪰ 0$.

How can it be shown that:
$$\det(A^2+AB+AC) \leq \det(A^2 +BA +AC+BC) ? \qquad (\star)$$

Where $A^2$ is symmetric and positive definite. Eigenvalues of $BA$, $AC$, and $BC$ are all $> 0$, but symmetry is lost.

Thank you!

Comment: $det(A^2+AB+AC) = det (A^2+A^{1/2}BA^{1/2} + A^{1/2}CA^{1/2})$, which are then all symmetric positive semi definite matrices. 

Comment: Even the inequality $(\star)$ is false; see below for another counterexample.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers.
Your counterexample is for the case where $A$ in $(\star)$ has a zero eigenvalue. My apologies, I hadn't made this clear in my initial question, but $A$ should be positive definite. I've edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: It still will not hold! even though $A$ turned out to be semidefinite in my example, you can see that a trivial epsilon perturbation will make it positive definite, but still yield a counterexample. I've included another explicit counterexample, including for the case where *all* three matrices are positive definite, so that you feel more convinced ;-)

Comment: Of course, you are right, but... now that's highly embarrassing: there's an error in my question, it should have been $BA$ all along!

Sorry for wasting you time. :-(

Comment: The fixed version with $BA$ does hold. The proof is interesting. If I get time, I'll type it out; otherwise someone else may want to do it.

Comment: I'd much appreciate it. But in any case, what's the direction/idea of your proof?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the original question has changed so much, I am writing a new answer.

The key point to recognize is that you are trying to prove a submodularity property. Indeed, we see that we may equivalently prove
\begin{equation*}
  \log\det(A) + \log\det(A+B+C) \le \log\det(A+B) +\log\det(A+C).
\end{equation*}
One common way to verify submodularity is to prove the *diminishing marginals* property: in our case, it amounts to showing that for a fixed $B \succeq 0$, the function
\begin{equation*}
 f(A) := \log\det(A+B)-\log\det(A)
\end{equation*}
is monotonically decreasing (since we are dealing with hermitian positive definite matrices, this means $f(A) \le f(C)$ if $C \succeq A$ in the semidefinite order).

To verify this, simply check if $\nabla f(A) \preceq 0$ for all $A$. But this is easy since

\begin{equation*}
 \nabla f(A) = (A+B)^{-1} - A^{-1} \preceq 0,
\end{equation*}
where the latter inequality follows as the map $X \mapsto X^{-1}$ is well-known to be (operator) decreasing.

Answer (score 3):

None of the conjectured inequalities hold.

This answer contains three counterexamples. The first one is to $(\star)$, while the second and third ones (below the line) refer to previous inequalities conjectured by the OP.

\begin{equation*}
  A=\begin{bmatrix} 5 & 5\\\\ 5 & 5\end{bmatrix},\quad
  B=\begin{bmatrix} 8 &4 \\\\ 4 & 2\end{bmatrix},\quad
  C=\begin{bmatrix} 8 &6 \\\\ 6 & 5\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

Then $A^2+AB+AC$ is a rank-1 matrix, so its determinant is zero, while $A^2+AB+AC+BC=\begin{bmatrix}268 & 203\\\\ 224 & 169\end{bmatrix}$, so its determinant is $-180$.

The structure of this counterexample and of the other ones below is to setup matrices so that the left hand side becomes a rank-1 matrix, which will have determinant zero. Then, one can adjust the other terms to violate inequalities in any direction.

*EDIT* I'm adding explicit matrices where $A,B,C \succ 0$, but still we have a counterexample to quell the OP's insistence ;-)

\begin{equation*}
A=\begin{bmatrix}11&12&7\\\\ 12 & 14 & 8\\\\ 7 & 8 & 11\end{bmatrix},\ 
B=\begin{bmatrix}19 &14&7\\\\ 14& 14&6\\\\ 7&6&3\end{bmatrix},\
C=\begin{bmatrix}17&17&16\\\\ 17&19&17\\\\ 16&17&17\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

For these matrices, $\det(A^2+AB+AC) \approx 2.35\times 10^5$, while $\det(A^2+AB+AC+BC) \approx 4.67 \times 10^4$.

---

A particularly cute counterexample for your last question (*edit*: where $\det(A+B) \ge \det(A)+\det(B)$ holds for non symmetric matrices with positive eigenvalues) is the following:

\begin{equation*}
 A = \begin{bmatrix}
     0.5 &         0 &         0&         0\\\\
    1    &    0.5 &        0 &        0\\\\
    1    &    1 &    0.5 &        0\\\\
    1    &    1 &   1   & 0.5
  \end{bmatrix},\quad B = A^T.
\end{equation*}

Then, $\det(A+B)=0$, but $\det(A)+\det(B) = 1/8$.

The updated question, whether $\det(XY+YZ) \ge \det(XY)+\det(YZ)$ holds is also false. Here is a nice counterexample.

\begin{eqnarray*}
  X = \begin{bmatrix}
   2 & 2\\\\
   2 & 2
  \end{bmatrix},\quad Y = \begin{bmatrix}
   5 & 5\\\\
   5 & 10
   \end{bmatrix},\quad Z = \begin{bmatrix}
   10 & 4\\\\
   4  & 2
   \end{bmatrix}.
\end{eqnarray*}
With this choice, $\det(XY+YZ) = -300$, while $\det(XY)+\det(YZ)=100$.

Comment: I see, so clearly $\det(A+B)\geq\det(A)+det(B)$ does not hold in general.

Nevertheless, decomposing your $A$ matrix using the [Jordan normal form][1] such that $A=BC$ yields $B$ and $C$ with both positive and negative eigenvalues.

Doing the same for a matrix $A=XY$ with $X$,$Y\succeq 0$ yields $B$,$C$ with positive eigenvalues (at least for the ones I tested).

Therefore I'd still suspect that the inequality
$\det(XY+YZ)\geq\det(XY)+det(YZ)$ with $X$,$Y$,$Z\succeq 0$
holds. But how to (dis-)prove it?

Tahnks.

Comment: Ups, my link disappeared: [1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Decomposition